# Android Resource leak try

Tags: android

Below are my codes, I'm having this weird warning: `Resource leak: 'br' is never closed` . Could anyone help me with this warning. I do not want my app to crash or cause any problems in the future.

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(sdcard,"/St/"+ textToPass);
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
        text.append('\n');
    }           
}catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error reading file!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
TextView output=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.st); 
// Assuming that 'output' is the id of your TextView
output.setText(text);
```

Comment: Close your br using br.close()?

Comment: Thanks. Forget about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't close your BufferedReader.

```
BufferedReader.close()
```

Will close both of your streams.

Answer (score 1):

here are the following [Link](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/369552/) and https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=361073

they suggested to use br.close()
try this one